# Will Lambda layers automatically be deleted after a certain time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, layer

I had read this somewhere but can't find the source. Is there any shelf life of added lambda layers so that they will be auto deleted after certain time period (like 1 year)?

Answer (score 1):

**I should hope not!**

The idea of layers are to decentratlise resources so multiple lambdas can access them.

Looking at [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) I didn't find anything that alludes to an expiry feature.